# Is it possible to define c-type variable in python and pass its address to cython wrapped function

Tags: python, c, cython

I am wrapping a C-library with Cython and for now I do not know how to workaround passing address to C function from python. Details below:

I have some C-function that takes address to some defined beforehand C variable and changes its value:

```c
void c_func(int* x) {
*x=5;
}
```

As a C user I can use this function in following way:

```c
def int var1
def int var2
c_func(&var1)
c_func(&var2)
```

After execution both `var1` and `var2` will be equal to 5. Now I want to wrap `c_func` with cython. I'd like to have `py_func` that might be imported from wrapper package and used, but I do not know how to define c variables from python.

What I have already done(in jupyter):

```py
%load_ext cython

%%cython

cdef int some_int

cdef extern from *:
    """
    void c_func(int* x) {
    *x=5;
    }

    """
    int c_func(int* x)

c_func(&some_int)

print(some_int)
```

What I want to get:

```py
%%cython

# This part should be in separate pyx file
cdef extern from *:
    """
    void c_func(int* x) {
    *x=5;
    }

    """
    int c_func(int* x)

def py_func(var):
    c_func(&var)

# The following part is user API
from wrapper import py_func

var_to_pass_in_py_func = ... # somehow defined C variable

py_func(var_to_pass_in_py_func) 

print(var_to_pass_in_py_func) # should print 5
```

`var_to_pass_in_py_func` might not be converted to python object, but C functions wrapped with python should not conflict with it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how your example makes sense in practice, but one possible way is to pass a buffer, which managed by python, to the C function. For example:

```
%%cython -a -f 

# Suppose this is the external C function needed to wrap
cdef void c_func(int* value_to_change):
    value_to_change[0] = 123;

def py_func(int[:] buffer_to_change):
    c_func(&buffer_to_change[0]);
```

---

```
from array import array
from ctypes import *

a = array('i', [0]);
py_func(a)
print(a[0])

b = (c_int*1)() # c_int array with length 1
py_func(b)
print(b[0])
```

Comment: thank you, cool answer. I try to adopt this code to my problem and instead of int I have type definition `typedef void* connection_t`. When I apply logic from the answer I get  an error: `Invalid base type for memoryview slice: connection_t`. If I am not mistaken the error occurs because unlike `int`, `void *` is not the base type. Do you have any suggestions, how to deal with this problem?